# Sqlalchemy - How to Specify Owner in Oracle database

Tags: python, oracle, sqlalchemy

I am trying to reflect an existing table from my database:

```
engine = sqlalchemy.create_engine("oracle://username:password@id", ...)
meta = sqlalchemy.MetaData()
myTable = sqlalchemy.Table("myTable", meta, autoload=True, autoload_with=engine,
                           oracle_resolve_synonyms=True)
```

That gave me an error:

> AssertionError: There are multiple tables visible to the schema, you must specify owner

How do I specify the owner in sqlalchemy? [The documentation](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/dialects/oracle.html#synonym-dblink-reflection) does not mention anything about specifying owners. the table is actually a synonym so I have to use `oracle_resolve_synonyms`. I can technically execute raw queries but that is not something that I want to do.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's the docs on MetaData: http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/metadata.html#sqlalchemy.schema.MetaData

You probably want to instantiate MetaData with the schema owner:

```
meta = sqlalchemy.MetaData(engine, schema='ora_schema_owner')
```

Comment: Nice! This is an even better solution because I don't have to specify it for every tables this way.

Answer (score 1):

After reading through the source code, I found out that the owner can be specified through [the `schema` keyword argument](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/metadata.html#specifying-the-schema-name):

```
myTable = sqlalchemy.Table("myTable", meta, autoload=True, autoload_with=engine,
                           oracle_resolve_synonyms=True, schema="ownerName")
```