# Flask-SQLalchemy, Oracle, and pre-pending Owner to queries

Tags: python, oracle, flask, flask-sqlalchemy

I've written a Flask app using flask-sqlalchemy.  My dev database username was the same as the oracle 'db owner'.  In production, they've given me a different read-only user.  The DBA has said I will need to prefix queries with the owner name in production.

For example:
A Flask-SQLAlchemy query might translate to `SELECT * from USERS;` in my Dev environment.
In production, my queries are supposed to look like:  `SELECT * from <owner>.USERS;`.

How do I prepend the owner to all of my queries without having to rewrite everything?  or do I need to ditch the ORM queries and write them native?

I think this is the ultimate solution, but I don't know how to implement it with Flask-SQLAlchemy: 
[Sqlalchemy - How to Specify Owner in Oracle database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49862366/sqlalchemy-how-to-specify-owner-in-oracle-database)

Answer (score 0):

Use the [cx_Oracle Connection.current_schema](https://cx-oracle.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api_manual/connection.html#Connection.current_schema) setting.